# Python XLWings: module 'xlwings._xlmac' has no attribute 'BOOK_CALLER'

Tags: python, xlwings

Trying to run a minimal piece of code in xlwings (ver 0.24.9) and I get the following error:

`AttributeError: module 'xlwings._xlmac' has no attribute 'BOOK_CALLER'`

Code:

```
import xlwings as xw

def world():
    wb = xw.Book.caller()
    wb.sheets[0].range('A1').value = 'Hello World!'

world()
```